# utPL/Sql testing contents of a table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, tdd

I've got  a table like this:

```
colors
----- 
red 
green 
blue
```

Is there a way to unit test for the existence of these other than writing a utAssert.eqqueryvalue(...) for each record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to build a test table with the expected results in the test fixture, and use `utAssert.eqTable()` to validate the outcome of running the code under test.  [Find out more](http://utplsql.sourceforge.net/Doc/utassert.html#utassert.eqtable).

The need to create heap tables to compare is unfortunate.  It puts a strain on the `Setup()` and requires transaction management.  Ideally we would like to have the comparison values in a collection, but there's no `utAssert` interface to compare a collection and a table.  But you could [build your own](http://utplsql.sourceforge.net/Doc/utassert.html#utassert-BYOA).

Alternatively do this:

```
utassert.eqquery (
  'Insert three colourns',
  'select * from YOUR_TABLE',
  'select ''red'' as colour from dual union all
   select ''green'' as colour from dual union all
   select ''blue'' as colour from dual'
);
```

Alas the more columns in your table the more tedious this will get.

Comment: Nice! You're talking my language.  I've the sense that you've been down this route a few times.  Your first option feels like the best fit if it could be an in-memory table.  (I don't care if I use collection or table, as long as either is easy.)  You said "transaction management," so that tells me it's got a lot of "system" involvement just to run an assert.  Your second option, use collections sounds like the way to go.  I'll keep my eye out for opportunities to get a new utAssert put together to do that.  I expect someone has done this already. I'll read up on your links. Thank you so much!

Comment: Oh, so yeah, I'll do your alternative and weigh it against my alternative, which has the negative of repeating myself 3-4 times (**red** for example):  `utAssert.eqqueryvalue (
        'missing red',
        'SELECT red FROM colors where thing like ''red''',
        'red' );  

    utAssert.eqqueryvalue (
        'missing green',
        'SELECT green FROM kitchen colors thing like ''green''',
        'green' );  ...`

Comment: Your last alternative (using dual union all) works very well. When the test fails, it leaves a sensible message:

Comment: Your last alternative using `dual union all` works quiet well and leaves a sensible error message when the assert fails. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you need complex solution - you can pass array of comma separated values into query and check that all the values exists in your table
if query below returns something - it means that test fails

```
SELECT EXTRACT (VALUE (d), '//row/text()').getstringval () as test_val
  FROM (SELECT XMLTYPE (   '<rows><row>'
                        || REPLACE ('red,green,blue', ',', '</row><row>')
                        || '</row></rows>'
                       ) AS xmlval
          FROM DUAL) x,
       TABLE (XMLSEQUENCE (EXTRACT (x.xmlval, '/rows/row'))) d
except
select colors from my_table
```

Comment: :-) You're obviously skilled. I'm looking for an easier one though. I'd like to avoid my team of mixed java/oracle skill people to maintain unit tests written in this pattern.  What will happen is we'll have a bunch of complicated tests that take time to understand.  Of course they could get accustom to this pattern, but it's a lot. Thanks for sharing this.

Comment: A good place for a solution of this complexity would be (as discussed later in APC's post) to make a procedure to handle this using the utAssert.XXX model and collections.  I'm surprised to yet find a short and succinct way to make a read only Table that's only in memory during the scope of a test procedure and doesn't require transactions.